# bash script to get modified file on remote server

Tags: bash, curl, libcurl

i want to connect to a secure ftp server and check inside each file inside a directory if its modification date is more than 3 days.

want to achieve this with a bash script using CURL.

here is what i have tried :

```
for i in `curl  -l -k --ftp-ssl ftp://"$ftp_username":"$ftp_password"@$ftp_ip:$ftp_port/$ftp_path/ `; do
{

    echo "Checking the modification date of $i";

    if ["$(( $(date +"%s") - $(stat -c "%Y" $i) ))" -gt "259200" ]; then
        echo "modified file found ";
    else
        echo "no modified file found";
    fi
};
done;
```

i get this error :

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0  3266    0     0   6980      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  7525
Checking the modification date of products
stat: cannot stat `products': No such file or directory
./remove_products.sh: line 18: 1373903124 -  : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "-  ")
```

what am i doing wrong ?

any help would be appreciated

Comment: The braces around the body of the `for` loop are unnecessary, as are the semicolons at the end of each line. (Note you do need the semicolon that precedes the keyword `do` when `do` is on the same line as the `for`.)

Comment: The `cannot stat` error implies that there's a file on the FTP server that doesn't exist locally. You're not checking for that case. Also, the loop won't work for files that have whitespace in their names.

Comment: LWP would make this task rather trivial.

Comment: how can i do that check ?

Comment: @user888300 you can check if a file exists with a [file test operator](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html). E.g. `if [ -e "$i" ]; then echo "it exists"; fi`

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
if ["$(( $(date +"%s") - $(stat -c "%Y" $i) ))" -gt "259200" ]; then
```

to:

```
if [ "$(( $(date +"%s") - $(stat -c "%Y" $i) ))" -gt "259200" ]; then
```

Spaces around the `[` are required.